# Extract a file containing 0|0,0|1,1|0 and 1|1

Tags: grep, wildcards

I have a csv file .Here is how it looks :

```
chr22,  Position ,  A     ,       B ,      C ,   D , E
22   ,  16050115 ,  0|0:404     ,  0     , 0    ,  0  ,    1|1:5
22    ,16050213    ,0|0:403  ,     0    ,  0   ,    0  ,   3|4:6
22 , 16050607  ,    1|0:340     , 1|1:3,  0   ,    0  ,    1|1:3
22   16050737 ,    0|0:402   ,   3|0:4 , 0|7:23 , 0  ,      0 
22 16050783  ,   0|0:404 ,       2|2:5 , 0|1:31 , 1|0:51,   0
```

`0|0:404` means the count of `0|0` is `404` and so on. I would like to extract only values of `0|0`,`1|0`,`0|1` and `1:1`
The output should be :

```
chr22, Position, A ,B, C ,D, E
22 ,16050115, 0|0:404 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1|1:5
22 ,16050213, 0|0:403, 0 ,0, 0, 0
22 ,16050607, 1|0:340, 1|1:3, 0 ,0 ,1|1:3
22 ,16050737, 0|0:402, 0 ,0 ,0, 0
22 ,16050783, 0|0:404 ,0 ,0|1:31 ,1|0:51, 0
```

I tried  `grep -e '0|0:' -e '1|1:' -e '0|1:' -e '1|1 /path/file.csv` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: png csv? doesn't really fulfill the [MCVE](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) criteria does it?

Comment: According to your description, your `grep` is doing the correct thing (apart from missing a `:` and a single quote at the end).  According to your expected output, your description of what you want to do is wrong. Please clarify either description or output.

Comment: Hi I have edited the file. The grep code doesn't work . It returns the output with values for 2|2,0|7...I want the values only for 0|0,0|1,1|0 and 1|1

Comment: I don't see `2|2` or `0|7` in your input?

Comment: I've attempted to format your CSV example. I think your original data was badly mangled because the result is ungainly. Please review and fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original command lines

I think the following command line will do it with a comma separated file by skipping 'offending' lines,

```
grep -v -e ', *[2-9]|' -e '|[2-9]:' file.csv
```

---

You can check with a small file with color,

```
grep -v -e ', *[2-9]|' -e '|[2-9]:' file.csv |grep --color '.|.'
```

and which lines are found by `grep` (excluded in the previous command lines by the option `-v`),

```
grep -e ', *[2-9]|' -e '|[2-9]:' file.csv |grep --color '.|.'
```

---

The following command line will do it with a tab separated file,

```
grep -v -e '\t[2-9]|' -e '|[2-9]:' Reddy.tab
```

or if you want a slightly looser check, the following command line can work,

```
grep -v -e '[2-9]|' -e '|[2-9]:' Reddy.tab file.csv
```

### Command line in response to a comment by the OP

I think the following command line will do what the OP wants with comma separated files as well as tab separated files,

```
sed -e 's/[2-9]|[0-9]:[0-9]*/NA/' -e 's/[0-9]|[2-9]:[0-9]*/NA/' file.csv
```

Comment: grep -v -e ',[2-9]|' -e '|[2-9]:' file.csv .I tried this but still it returns values for 2|2,0|7 ..

Comment: @AdhiraReddy, 1. Is the file comma separated `file.csv` or space separated as your new illustration? 2. Can there be numbers greater than 9 in the expression `num1|num2`?

Comment: Sorry I have edited my post again. Ya my file is csv. No the numbers are less than 9

Comment: @AdhiraReddy, It seems your file is tab separated. Please try with the command lines, that I have added to the answer.

Comment: @AdhiraReddy, I have modified the first command for comma separated files to allow for spaces near the commas.

Comment: ,Thank you so much . It works .I tried both for csv and .tab files

Comment: @AdhiraReddy, You are welcome. I'm glad I could help :-)

Comment: instead of skipping the offending lines , how do I make them NA or zero

Comment: @AdhiraReddy, What do you want converted to NA or zero? Do you mean the whole line, or the particular offending data in a column?

Comment: ,I want only the entry of the offending data to be NA/0.For example 22   16050115 ,  0|0:404     ,  0     , 0    ,  0  ,    2|1:5 should give me            16050115 ,  0|0:404     ,  0     , 0    ,  0  ,    NA

Comment: @AdhiraReddy, Try the new command line at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if `grep` is a requirement for this case, but using `perl`, you could do something like this to remove the unwanted items:

```perl
perl -pe 's/, ?[2-9]\d*\|\d+:\d+//g; s/, ?\d+\|[2-9]\d*:\d+//g' /path/to/file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
grep -e '[01]|[01]:'
```

<s>where `|` need to be escaped, as `0|1` means either 0 or 1.</s>

note that

```
grep -e '0|0:' -e '1|1:' -e '0|1:' -e '1|1:'
```

match the same.

filtering on a column :

```
awk -F, '$3 ~/[01]|[01]:/ '
```

where `$3` is third column.

filtering column 3 and above

```
awk -F, '{printf "%s,%s",$1,$2 ; 
      for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) 
        if ( $i  ~ /[01]\|[01]:/) 
           printf ",%s",$i ; 
      printf "\n" }'
```

that can be one lined.

- note that `|` in this case, need to be escaped.
- note also that first line is filtered out

  ```
  chr22,Position
  22,16050115,0|0:404,1|1:5
  22,16050213,0|0:403
  22,16050607,1|0:340,1|1:3,1|1:3
  22,16050737,0|0:402
  22,16050783,0|0:404,0|1:31,1|0:51
  ```

Comment: It doesnt work .I tried both the codes